# Making sense of the Geo Performance Report in Google Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to understand the [geo performance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report) in the Adwords API. Specifically, this note is tripping me up

> Note: If you request both IsTargetingLocation values in your predicate and either do not limit by LocationType or request both LocationType values in your predicate, then the same impression's statistics may appear in multiple rows of the report. Therefore, statistic totals from your report could be much higher than totals from other reports such as the CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT.

The way I understand it is, campaigns have a target location like New York. The field *IsTargetingLocation* can be true or false, where true means the corresponding impressions occurred in the target location and false means they didn't.

Additionally, the field *LocationType* can be either "Location of interest" (someone in Alabama is interested in New York) or "Physical location".

How can including both of these fields create double-counting? Someone is either in New York (IsTargetingLocation = true and LocationType = "Physical location") or they aren't (IsTargetingLocation = false and LocationType = "Location of interest").

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the `IsTargetingLocation` field indicates whether this was an actively targeted location, i.e. a CampaignCriterion of type [`LOCATION`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/CampaignCriterionService.Location) was triggering the impression.

So, if you target New Yorkers and somebody is looking for content about California, two impressions will be returned:

- One for New York with `LocationType` "Physical Location" and the `IsTargetingLocation` flag set
- An additional one for California with `LocationType` "Location of interest" and the `IsTargetingLocation` flag not set

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Unless you have a source though, I'm going to wait a few days for others to chime in before accepting this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Ben I've looked through the Adwords API forum and couldn't find a specific definition of `IsTargetingLocation`. However this should be simple to test, just set up a small test campaign where you only target one specific location and check the Geo Performace Report after you collect a couple of impressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better understanding of this now..

When you set up a campaign, you set up target locations. For example, suppose I target New York. I can choose to apply this target via physical location, location of interest, or both.

[image]

Suppose I've chosen to target people based on both location criteria..

## Scenario 1:

Bob is physically located in New York, and he searches for "pizza restaurants". In this case, the geo performance report should return one record like

```
   Location IsTargetingLocation         LocationType
1: New York                TRUE LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE
```

## Scenario 2:

Bob is physically located in New York, and he searches for "new york pizza restaurants". In this case, the geo performance report should return two records like

```
   Location IsTargetingLocation         LocationType
1: New York                   ? LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE
2: New York                   ? LOCATION_OF_INTEREST
```

In this case, I suspect one row will have `IsTargetingLocation = TRUE` and the other will be `FALSE`. The question is, did Google show Bob our ad because he was interested in New York or because he was physically located in New York? I suspect google attributes the ad display to one of these and not both, but I could be wrong here.

## Scenario 3:

Bob is physically located in California, and he searches for "new york pizza restaurants". In this case, the geo performance report should return two records like

```
     Location IsTargetingLocation         LocationType
1: California               FALSE LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE
2:   New York                TRUE LOCATION_OF_INTEREST
```